# system-config-keyboard not working on Fedora

Tags: linux, localization, keyboard, fedora

I've got a VM under Fedora 23, but it is configured with the default english keyboard layout for the console
The thing is, that I'm not english or american, and my keyboard does look totally different.

I read that you can change this with system-config-keyboard, which I did but it did not work.

I come to the conclusion that my locale is not installed: in /usr/share/i18n/locales I can find only en_* files.
So I tried dnf langinstall fr_FR, but I've got the error No langpacks to install for: fr_FR

So, does anyone know, on Fedore, how to install a new locale, and then configure the console ketboard layout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one has a clue? Losing so much time on this stupid problem is really annoying... Debugging something when your keyboard layout is false, is just impossible. How come is it so difficult to change a keyboard layout???

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution: you have to install package "kdb" to install other keyboard layout.

It's a pity that system-config-keyboard does not raise an error when selecting a layout not available on the system.